# A word for words with same meaning, same pronunciation but different language & origin

Tags: single-word-requests

How to call in English words which coincidentally happen to share the same pronunciation and the same meaning but belong to two distinct languages that are linguistically unrelated? I'm thinking of the word 'earth', among a few other words, which is pronounced 'arth' in Arabic and means the same thing as in English.

Comment: Dear me, I thought it was just a few words -- turns out to be dozens of them according to this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AList_of_Arabic_loanwords_in_English

Answer (score 9):

They are called [***false cognates***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate). From the Wikipedia:

> *False cognates* are pairs of words that seem to be cognates because of similar sounds and meaning, but actually have different etymologies; these word pairs can be within the same language or be from different ones. This is different from false friends, which may in fact be related but have different meanings. Even though false cognates lack a common root, there may still be an indirect connection between them (for example through phono-semantic matching or folk etymology).

Some examples given in the same page are:

- English *ache* and Ancient Greek *ἄχος* (ákhos) (pain, distress)
- English *bad*, Persian *bad*, and Armenian *vad* (ւադ) (bad)
- English *chill*, *chilly* and Quechua *chiri, chili* "cold"
- English *cut* and French *couteau* "knife"
- English *day, daily* and Spanish *día* (day) (or Latin *dies* (day) or even English *diary*
- French *feu* (fire) and German *Feuer* (fire)
- German *haben* and Latin *habere* (both "have")
- Hindi *sant* and English *saint*

A term used in biology but also applicable to linguistics is [***convergent evolution***](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=convergent+evolution+linguistics):

> Pinker and Bloom (1990) and others assume that linguistic universals provide evidence for a language faculty, but if languages evolve to adapt to the inductive bias in the human learning procedure, then linguistic universals need not be genetically-encoded constraints, but instead may just be a consequence of convergent evolution towards more learnable grammatical systems. Again to quote Deacon (1997:116) "universal[s]... emerged spontaneously and independently in each evolving language, in response to universal biases in the selection processes affecting language transmission. They are convergent features of language evolution in the same way that the dorsal fins of sharks, ichthyosaurs, and dolphins are independent convergents adaptations of aquatic species."
>
> Briscoe, T. (Ed.). (2002). *Linguistic evolution through language acquisition.* Cambridge University Press.

Convergent evolution would imply there were some forces that shaped a given word so it would sound similar across different languages. Some examples are the interjection [*Huh?*](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0078273) or the indefinite article *an* in English and Yiddish (according to [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/61/examples-of-convergent-evolution)). ["Mama" and "papa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mama_and_papa) were also thought to be the result of linguistic convergence, although such idea has been criticised (see [The Age of Mama and Papa](http://sociology.sunimc.net/htmledit/uploadfile/system/20110313/20110313165102325.pdf#page=442), by Matthey and Bancel). If there's no evidence both words evolved from different origins but got to be similar because of a similar evolutionary pressure, then *false cognates* is the best term.

Comment: I find it strange though that the interjection for the feeling of pain is different in many languages -- for instance, aeħ! or weħ! in Arabic, aïe! in French and ouch! in English!

Comment: Nicely done....

Comment: The question is how to distinguish then false cognates from borrowed words!

Comment: Where can I find etymologies of foreign words?

Comment: @Chaim in etymological dictionaries of the languages those words are from. examples: [English](http://www.etymonline.com/), [French](https://www.etymologie.exionnaire.com/), [lots of others](http://www.lexilogos.com/etymologie.htm)

Comment: @Mitch. Thanks. I'd say that's a good solid base hit. A homer would allow me to enter a foreign word and find the surrounding explanation in English. Got anything like that?

Comment: @Chaim That sounds like a general translation situation, an English-X/X-English dictionary. Anyway, someone who is looking for the etymology of languages in any language (even if unknown to the user) should probably have facility with all the available language tools. Short answer: use Google translate alongside online dictionaries. Always use more than one dictionary, etymological or not. A meta-solution: ask your question on linguistics.SE or language learners.SE (I'm not sure if they allow questions on references).

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the very interesting term ***false friends***. If the two words meant the same thing, they would be called ***cognates***. But two words from different languages, with different meanings, but which sound the same, are called false friends.

EDIT: I'll agree that **false cognates** seems correct. What I know for sure is that I misinterpreted "linguistically unrelated" and read "linguistically related." My fault. Sorry if I misled you.

Comment: I always understood that cognates *are* historically related.

Comment: Can you give a reference link please?

Comment: The word I'm looking for is definitely not cognates!

Comment: As @DavidGarner suggests, *cognate* means, literally, "co-born", and it is used only of words which have a common ancestor (though the lines of descent may diverge through different daughter languages). It is not used of words which are not historically related.

Comment: Wrong on all counts: [cognates](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/cognate_1?q=cognate) have the same origin, and not necessarily the same meaning or pronunciation.